# Connect Google Earth with Omnet++

Tags: networking, google-earth, omnet++

I'm trying to make a simulation of communication in Vanet to avoid vehicule collision  using omnet++ 4,and I want to show the virtualization in Google Earth.
Can any one tell me how to show the result in Google earth ?

Comment: You need to generate KML from your results to view in Google Earth. First review [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/) what KML can and cannot do. See also [Google Earth Blog](https://www.gearthblog.com/) for examples and ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Use osgEarth in OMNeT++ 5.1. There is even an example (samples/osgearth) that shows you the details, it is a MUCH more usable approach.